# Rails - How to find tilt version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets, tilt

Gem `tilt` is used with `sprockets` for Rails assets precompile. We are having hard time to find the version running on our Rails 4 app as `tilt --version` returns `version unknown`:

```
$ tilt --version
tilt: version unknown
```

`tilt --help` give no info about how to find version. Is there way to find `tilt` version?

Comment: Have you tried `bundle show tilt`?

Comment: bundle works. I will mark as answer if you post it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bundle show` to get the versions of your installed gems.  For a particular gem, like tilt, you can use `bundle show tilt`.